# Markdown short links in off-topic reasons not being expanded in review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, markdown-rendering

While going through the close-votes review queue on this very site, I was faced with not only a question that was "not … about Stack Overflow … [as] defined in the help center" (a built-in reason), but also a failure to properly cook the Markdown in that message:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed, and will be deployed in build 3762 on MSO/MSE, and build 2883 on other sites.

Our comments, close reasons, chat messages, etc. are processed using a system called MarkdownMini (a completely separate engine from the one used for posts themselves). MarkdownMini has a flag for specifying whether to process magic links (or "short links" as you called them; these are separate from normal Markdown links, which are always processed). This has now been enabled for custom off-topic close reasons.